# Wildcard domain validator

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am going to add support of wildcards to my application.

**It should meet the requirement below. Wildcards must contain:**

```
 - UTF-8 alphabetical characters
 - .,*,^,+,?,$,[],[^],:,/
 - Domain parts other than the last may begin with a digit(from RFCs)
```

Also user can specified simple domain name as `test.test`

The idea was to do it in two steps:

1. Validate whether wildcard matches with pattern below:

   `^[\\pL0-9\\[\\].^$?*+:/]+`. If it match it try to compile as java pattern.
2. If it does not match last regex then assume that is simple domain name and validate it using google library `com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName`

But I am not sure whether **last approach will be cover all possible cases**.

As example when I specified domain like this:
`test.10` it matches with pattern but it does not meet the third requirements regarding to digits in domains.

It would be good if your suggestion explains how can I meet all defined requirements. Also it will be good to know a better solution in such cases.

Comment: `(^[\\pL0-9\\[\\].^$?*+:/]+\\.)?^[\\pL\\[\\].^$?*+:/]+`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I've tried your patter. But unfortunatly it does not work as expected. So it does not match the following domains that considered valid with third requirement: 10test.com, test.10test.com

Answer (score 1):

If the last part of the Domain should not contain any numbers:

```
^(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\x2A\x2B\x2F\x3A\x3F\x5B\x5D\x5E]+[\x2E])+[\p{L}\x2A\x2B\x2F\x3A\x3F\x5B\x5D\x5E]+$
```

The regex above as Java String:

```
"^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}\\x2A\\x2B\\x2F\\x3A\\x3F\\x5B\\x5D\\x5E]+[\\x2E])+[\\p{L}\\x2A\\x2B\\x2F\\x3A\\x3F\\x5B\\x5D\\x5E]+$"
```

---

If only the first character of the last part of the domain shouldn`t be a number:

```
(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\x2A\x2B\x2F\x3A\x3F\x5B\x5D\x5E]+[\x2E])+[\p{L}\x2A\x2B\x2F\x3A\x3F\x5B\x5D\x5E][\p{L}\p{N}\x2A\x2B\x2F\x3A\x3F\x5B\x5D\x5E]+
```

The regex above as Java String:

```
"(?:[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}\\x2A\\x2B\\x2F\\x3A\\x3F\\x5B\\x5D\\x5E]+[\\x2E])+[\\p{L}\\x2A\\x2B\\x2F\\x3A\\x3F\\x5B\\x5D\\x5E][\\p{L}\\p{N}\\x2A\\x2B\\x2F\\x3A\\x3F\\x5B\\x5D\\x5E]+"
```